# I have an old light fixture in my bathroom with no visible screws; how do I remove it from the ceiling?

Tags: light-fixture, ceiling

[image][image]I'd like to replace an old, rusted light fixture on the bathroom ceiling.  Unfortunately, I have no idea how it's actually held up to the ceiling.  There are no screws on the sides, but there are holes.  When I put my finger in to feel for a screw, it seems to only be insulation.  I read that it may be spring-loaded?  The whole thing does move; I can spin it counter-clockwise and clockwise, but I'm afraid to keep spinning.  Is this how it comes down?  Any tips are appreciated!  [image]

Comment: Don't spin it--you'll spin the wiring.  If it's spring loaded, try gently prying one end to see if you see spring clips.  Also, a higher resolution photo of the fixture with the insulation removed will help.

Answer (score 2):

The nut in the center on the hollow shaft is the way the fixture is held in place that is called a hickey, yes there are multiple terms in electrical language the other electrical hickey is a pipe bender.

Comment: That's the answer!  Unscrewed the center and down it came.  Very grateful for your help - thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you pull away some of the foil insulation you'll find the screws, probably 2, that hole the fixture to the junction box where the wire connections will be.

Comment: Thank you.  I pulled the foil back, but it just exposed some toasted foam. I pulled the foam down as much as I could and unfortunately, no screws underneath.

Comment: What about right in the center?

Comment: Yes, that did it!  The center was the answer.  I cut away the insulation and took a pair of plyers to the center.  Thankfully it moved easier than I expected.  Came straight down.  Thanks very much for your help!